# Phaser Arcade Physics Debug Body Stopped Working

Tags: phaser-framework

I have never had this issue with Phaser before.  I'm using Phaser-2.6.2 and for some reason, all of the sudden, I can no longer debug my physics bodies.  Inside of render I have something as simple as:

```
this.game.debug.body(this.hero);
this.game.debug.body(this.boss);
```

This used to work, not sure why something this basic would all of the sudden stop working.  Is there a simple fix for this?  I tried creating a new project from scratch and am having the same problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I am going to try it on the latest Phaser release 2.8.1.

Comment: Have you tried setting a `debugger` statement to check if the code is reached, and also if `this.hero.body` exists?

Comment: Adding to BdR, can you provide a longer example of code that doesn't work? As it is, that appears to be the code that's required, and it works based on https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/body-debug